# Set an ipv6-specific MTU

Tags: ipv6, tunnel, mtu

I have a router which has ipv6 connectivity through a tunneling mechanism. The router announces a prefix in the LAN, and clients get native ipv6 connectivity on their point of view. The MTU of the LAN is 1500, but the MTU of the ipv6 tunnel is lower: how do I force the clients to have a MTU of 1500 for ipv4 but a lower value for ipv6 packets, to avoid fragmentation at the point of the router?

Comment: AFAIK, fragmentation by the router is explicitly *forbidden* in IPv6, so I doubt that's going to be a problem.

Comment: Path MTU discovery takes care of this for you; you shouldn't need to bother. If you are having a _specific_ MTU-related problem, you should describe it.

Comment: You should also say exactly what router you are using and whose tunnel service.